# Providing JavaCompiler within program

Tags: java, compilation

I would like to know if there is a `JavaCompiler` library for me to provide within my jar file, so users can run my program, which uses a `JavaCompiler`, also with a JRE?

*Because a `JavaCompiler` is only implemented in a JDK and therefore a user has to use a JDK for their runtime environment.
Common users have a JRE installed.*

Comment: *"Common users have JRE installed."*  Common users play games & prepare documents, they don't tend to compile code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache Commons JCI](http://commons.apache.org/jci/usage.html). It should provide what you want.